# How to spawn enemies randomly each level in a game

Tags: java

I am making a relatively simple game in Java in which the objective is to survive different levels of enemies. 
Every level one to two more enemies are added to the already existing enemies, and every tenth level there is a boss battle.

Example: If level one spawns one enemy, level two can spawn one or two, added to the already existing one. If level two spawns two enemies, level three can also spawn an additional one to two enemies. The tenth level will always have a boss battle with a definite enemy type of Boss.

A sample of the spawning system is shown below:

```
if (hud.getLevel() == 2) {
    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
}
```

The game is meant to go on for a pseudo-infinite amount of time, but that is impossible to do with this kind of system. How would I configure it to spawn one or to enemies each level forever?

**EDIT:** Also, I should note that I have multiple types of enemies.

Comment: By "one or two" do you mean, level 1 has 1 enemy, 2 has 2, and 3 has 1, and so on, or do you mean random chance of 1 or 2?

Comment: Random chance of one or two, yes

Comment: The example you're describing does not really follow any pattern that I can see, you'd have to figure one out yourself. But check my answer; random generation is how this will need to be done.

Comment: I have modified my answer to accommodate your generation algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this would be pretty simple. I'm assuming you already have a system in place that switches levels and all you're looking for is spawning. This is how I would do it:

```
// your fields
Random r = new Random();
int lastAmount = 0;

// your spawning method
if(hud.getLevel % 10 != 0) {
    int amount = r.nextInt(2) + 1 + lastAmount;
    lastAmount = amount;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        // you can have another random generation for enemy types in here
        handler.addObject(... // add your enemy
    }
} else {
    // spawn your boss
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first level, we have 2 enemies. Then 4. Then 6. Then 7. And so on. So we could do something like the following to increase the number each level, where `hud.getLevel() * 2` is the number of enemies:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hud.getLevel() * 2; ++i) {
    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
}
```

Comment: Ah, note that this is a non-random way of doing things.

Comment: I think a simple random.nextBoolean and if-statement would solve that

Comment: You would be the expert, SomeRandomGuy!! :) Yeah, one solution would to add/subtract some random number from the control value in the loop. OP: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html for info on generating random numbers!

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't exactly fit what I was looking for. I edited my post to be a bit more specific, if you wanna look at it again :)